# treating my entity framework list as a list of poco

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

Not sure if I am asking this correctly (i am new to EF).

Basically here is my problem. I have a class called Cities, which is a really simple class but it maps my db table exactly

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    public City()
{
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
}
}
```

Now later in my system i have a list of cities
    public List Cities { get; private set; }

and a linq query as such

```
using (MYdbEntities myentity = new MYdbEntities())
        {
           var efCities = (from c in myentity.Cities
                      orderby c.CityName
                      select c);           
            Cities = efCities.ToList();  //this line croaks           
        }
```

So i get that the problem is that the linq returns a list of entities from the model, while Cities is a list of City objects which is different.
but how can i cast efCities into Cities (short of doing a horrible loop with my own mappings blech)

I google ad get bizarre stuff about T4 generated templates something something
pls dumb it down for me :)

I would like to keep my City object as simple as possible without any knowledge of Entity Framework because I plan to use it elsewhere

Thanks

Comment: Are you using EF code-first (>4.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, your cities class (model) is not the same at the one created by EF but has the same of similar propertie.

The simplest way based on what you have is to

```
var myCities = (efCities.Select(o=> new City() { 
   Id = o.Id, 
   Country = o.Country
   ....
 }).ToList();
```

Please excuse formatting, difficult on iPad.

Basically what you're doing is creating new list of your City class mapping each property in the Select function.

You can alternatively use something like AutoMapper to map / populate your Cities class automatically. You can find AutoMapper here http://automapper.codeplex.com/.

Hope that helps

Sam

Comment: hmmmm, i think i understand, but not sure where the new MyCities() comes from

Comment: Yeah, sorry for some reason I thought your city class was named (poorly) cities and was trying to differentiate. I've edited answer :)

Comment: thanks. works like a bomb. still new to c# so didnt know i could map fields like that using the =>   really powerful

Comment: No problem. The parameter you pass to the Select() method is called a lambda expression. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx. In my example it's actually an anonymous function that creates a new City object. The select function calls the anonymous function for each object in the efCitities collection. You then call ToList() which converts the IEnumerable<City> to a List<City>.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method `CopyTo` to copy the properties of source object to destionation object(with same names). Your `select c` would be now `select c.CopyTo<City>()`

Example:

```
public class City1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}

public class City2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}

City2 c2 = new City2();
new City1() { 
      Id = 3, Country = "aaa", Province = "bbb", CityName = "ccc" }
.Copy(c2);

//or

City2 c2 = new City1() { 
             Id = 3, Country = "aaa", Province = "bbb", CityName = "ccc" }
           .Copy<City2>();
```

.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void CopyTo(this object src, object to)
    {
        Type dstType = to.GetType();
        foreach (var prop in src.GetType()
                                .GetProperties()
                                .Select(pi => new { Name = pi.Name, Value = pi.GetValue(src, null) }))
        {
            dstType.GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(to, prop.Value, null);
        }
    }

    public static T CopyTo<T>(this object src)
    {
        Type dstType = typeof(T);
        T to = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(dstType);
        CopyTo(src, to);
        return to;
    }
}
```